# React will see a new component type on every render and destroy the entire subtree's DOM nodes and state. Move the definition outside of the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Problem: React will see a new component on every render and destroy the entire subtree' DOM Nodes and state. Instead move this component definition out of the parent and pass data as props.

```
const Component2 = (props) => { // just a displayer component
    return (
        <div>
            {props.data}
        </div>
    );
}

const Component1 = (props) => {
    const onSubmitHandler = useCallback(() => {
        const config = {
            customComponents: {
                header: (props) => <Component2 {...props}/>
            }
        }

      // submit action
    }, []);
}
```

Due to the restrictions, `header` accepts only a function: `(props) => <CustomComponent {...props} />` and I do not want the Custom Component to re-render in a way that destroys the subtree DOM as per the warning.

Can someone guide me on this?

> As extra information, I encountered this problem in react-chatbot-kit if it makes sense

Comment: The Component2 is only being used inside Component1. This is a snapshot of one single file where Component2 is placed outside Component1

Comment: "`header` accepts only a function": `Component2` is a function and  you can use `header: Component2`. This will make `header` a constant function component and not a transient one, which react should handle better.